# How to know if a user can read and list files of a directory

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a folder in my computer and i used DirectoryInfo to get all files in that folder. But, this is using my user account. I have to use the permissions of anouther user account, and i need to know if this other account can read and list the files in that folder.

Here is the code that i wrote to get the files:

```
DirectoryInfo Folder = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
FileInfo[] Files = Folder.GetFiles(search, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

What i was expecting is that exists a way to do something like that:

```
DirectoryInfo Folder = new DirectoryInfo(folderName, UserCredentials);
```

And if this user don't have permission this line thows an exception or perhaps a way to check the user permissions.

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function to check permissions of a directory for another user:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
public static FileSystemRights GetDirectoryPermissions(string user, string domainName, string folderPath)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        return (0);
    }

    string identityReference = ((domainName + @"\" + user) as string).ToLower();
    DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(folderPath, AccessControlSections.Access);
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule fsRule in dirSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
    {
        if (fsRule.IdentityReference.Value.ToLower() == identityReference)
        {
            return (fsRule.FileSystemRights);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

It returns the flags in case user have any permissions, otherwise it will return 0. you can change it to check files permissions too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to call the SetAccessControl method on the DirectoryInfo object to accomplish this.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx for more information on this method.

Answer (score 1):

see the below example

```
public bool CheckFolderPermissions(string folderPath)
{
 WindowsIdentity currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
 var domainAndUser = currentUser.Name;
 DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
 DirectorySecurity dirAC =     dirInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
 AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = dirAC.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

 foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
 {
     if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(domainAndUser, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
     {
         if ((((FileSystemAccessRule)rule).FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.WriteData) > 0)
         return true;
     }
  }
 return false;
}
```